# Cancel ActiveMQ message

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I'm not sure if ActiveMQ is a right tool here...

I have a task queue and multiple consumers, so my idea was to use ActiveMQ to post tasks, which are then consumed by consumers.

But I need to be able to cancel the task, if it was not processed yet...

Is there an API for removing Message from Queue in ActiveMQ?

```
Destination destination = session.createQueue(TOPIC_NAME);
MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
ObjectMessage message = session.createObjectMessage(jobData);
producer.send(message);
...
producer.cancel(message); (?)
```

The use-case is that, for any reason, performing the task is no longer needed, and the task is resource-consuming.

Comment: You mean cancel message if they are not delivered to any consumer at given point of time?

Comment: @SagarRohankar exactly, once delivered, they won't be in queue anymore...

Comment: Will this help: http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-purge-a-queue.html

Comment: @SagarRohankar no, because I want to remove only a single particular message, leaving all others intact.

Comment: Again, hope this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11413233/4222629

Comment: @SagarRohankar so you suggest I create some attribute, fill it with (arbitrary) ID, and then I can lookup using that attribute name and ID?

Comment: Yes, something similar, I hope the task you are queuing must got some id and you know which tasks u no more required.

Answer (score 1):

What about setting an expiry time on the message? 
http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-set-the-message-expiration.html

If you want a message to be deleted if it has not been processed / consumed in a particular time frame, then message expiry seems the answer to me.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveMQ exposes a JMX interface that allows for operations of this kind. The MBean that models a Queue (e.g., org.apache.activemq:type=broker,brokerName=amq,destinationType=Queue,destinationName=my_queue) exposes a method removeMessage (String id). There are also methods that remove messages that match a particular pattern.

So far as I know, this functionality is not exposed outside JMX.

But...

I have a nasty feeling that JMX operations that work on specific messages only work on messages that are paged into memory. By default that would usually be the 400 messages nearest the head of the queue. I know this is true for selector operations, although I'm not sure about JMX.

Some ActiveMQ message stores (e.g., the JDBC store) might also provide a way to get to the underlying message data and manipulate it. On a relational database this is usually safe to do, because messages that are 'in flight' in a JMS operation will be locked at the database level. However, this is a lot of hassle for what ought to be a simple job.

I wonder if JMS is really the right technology for this job? It isn't really intended for random access. Perhaps some sort of distributed data cache would work better (jgroups, Hazelcast,...)?

Answer (score 0):

For those who are looking for a direct answer, there's a JMS API to control this behaviour:

Per [JMS API docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/JMSProducer.html):

> `setTimeToLive(long timeToLive)`
>
> Specifies the time to live of messages that are sent using this `JMSProducer`.

So you can set this value on the producer before sending:

```
...
producer.setTimeToLive(30000L);
producer.send();
```

With this particular setting, messages will be retained for 30 seconds before being deleted by the Message Broker